# Make GNOME Characters use different emoji font?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, fonts, unicode, emoji

[image]

How do I configure which emoji font **GNOME Character app** uses? Currently it's using Noto Emoji Color.

- GNOME 45.3
- Arch Linux

Comment: One way is to delete/uninstall all emoji fonts on the system and then place your desired emoji font in `~/.local/share/fonts/` and then run `fc-cache -f -v`